# AutoIt RDP connect

Tags: windows, autoit, rdp

Having some issues figuring out automation for RDP on win10. Would appreciate any tips you guys got.

What I am trying to accomplish:

Use an AutoIt script to:

1. Open a remote desktop connection
2. Check 'Don't ask me again for connections to this computer', click
   connect
3. Allow for remote desktop to load
4. Disconnect

Attempted to run the remote desktop connection with mstsc.exe, but got the error

[image]

The shortcut name is

[image: image.png.49080350cbb44767fea27ea67c795b88.png]

My code so far

[image]

Have also tried `Run("C:\Users\Public\Desktop\RDP Consoles\administrator@windows-1")` to no avail.

Anyone know why I am getting this error? Or of a better way to perform this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Run()` actually starts a `cmd` process, so you have to obey the rules of `cmd` too.

`cmd` expects filenames with spaces (and some other "poison chars") to be quoted (and it has to be double-qoutes). In your example, you run `mstsc` with *two* parameters: `C:\Users\Public\Desktop\RDP` and `Consoles\administrator@windows-1`. To make it *one* parameter, quote it. Best practice: also quote any paths or filenames (to again avoid problems with spaces):

```
$x=Run('"C:\Windows\system32\mstsc.exe" "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\RDP Consoles\administrator@windows-1.rdp"', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope. On my Win 7 Ultimate and my Windows Server 2019 it sure works this way:

```
Run("C:\Windows\system32\mstsc.exe")
WinWaitActive("Remote Desktop Connection","")
Send("Put your Remote Desktop IP here")
Send("{ENTER}")
WinWaitActive("Windows Security","")
Send("Put your Remote Desktop user name here")
Send("{TAB}")
ClipPut("Put your Remote Desktop password here")
Send("^v")
Send("{ENTER}")
```